# Webservice call from WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web-services, wcf

We have an existing web service (SOAP/XML) which is windows authenticated. We are adding a new WCF service which has anonymous authentication. When calling a function from the existing web service from the WCF service I get the following error

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

We do have other console and web applications calling the existing service with no issues.

I tried setting the `UseDefautlCredentials` to `True` and does not make a difference (`WS.UseDefaultCredentials = True`).

Also tried adding the existing service as a service reference as opposed to a web reference and I get a different error

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.

I really do not want to change the authentication to anonymous on the existing web service since it is AD authenticated.

Would really appreciate any kind of help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any code to post?

Comment: @L.B
pretty straight forward....  
    Dim ecomWS As New EcomWS.EcometryPayment  
    Dim ecomOrdDtTab As New DataTable  
    ecomWS.UseDefaultCredentials = True  
    ecomOrdDtTab = ecomWS.GetEcometryOrders

Answer (score 0):

Your problem it's something called double hop.
You have some options, use kerberos, pass in your code a valid credentials when your are calling a soap service or impersonate your wcf service, but you have to test it. 
`<serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />`

Comment: Thanks, makes sense that the credentials wouldn't be making it to the existing web service. I did try `<serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />` and had to set `<OperationBehavior(Impersonation:=ImpersonationOption.Required)>` for it to work. I get a different error now 
> Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid.
I also tried setting the `endpointBehavior` like so `<windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Impersonation" />` which did not help.
Kerberos or passing credentials is not an option unfortunately.